# difference between conditional comments <!--[if lt IE 9]> and <!--[if lte IE 8]>

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8, conditional-statements

Is there any difference between conditional comments `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` and `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`

The first one of course means less than IE9.

The second one means less than or equal IE8.

Are they equivalent or not?

Comment: Seems easily testable. Did you try it?

Comment: @j08691 Yes. And if I find a difference, I won't ask at all.

Comment: So then what problems did you encounter that caused you to ask the question?

Comment: @j08691  I thought I may place two javascript files one for <!--[if lt IE 9]> and another one for <!--[if lte IE 8]> into one conditional statement to simplify the code. However I decided to ask here as probably there was a reason for that. That two files comes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if Internet Explorer 8.X does not exist, **YES** they are equivalent !

Answer (score 1):

if there is a version IE 8.x it will be deny by lte IE8 but accept by lt IE9

but as Ksv3n say, there is no IE8.x, so on this case they are equivalent